# How to trim variables without erring if the var is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following for event tracking:

```
var dataTrack = e.split(','); // split by comma

if (dataTrack !== undefined) {

    var action = dataTrack[0];
    var values = {};
    values[dataTrack[1]] = dataTrack[2];

    mpq.track(action, values);
}
```

How can I trim dataTrack[0], dataTrack[1], dataTrack[2] in a way where if any of the dataTrack vars are empty it won't break? 1 & 2 are optional...

Thanks

Comment: `split` always returns an array, so checking against `undefined` is pretty useless. You should rather check `e` against `undefined` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A common idiom in JavaScript is to provide default values like so:

```
// default to the empty string
var dataTrack0 = dataTrack[0] || '',
    dataTrack1 = dataTrack[1] || '',
    dataTrack2 = dataTrack[2] || '';
```

...though I think a better solution, in this case, might be to check the `length` of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [length property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp) for the array.

```
var dataTrack = e.split(','); // split by comma

if (dataTrack !== undefined) {

    var action = dataTrack[0];
    var values = {};
    if(dataTrack.length > 2) {
        values[dataTrack[1]] = dataTrack[2];
    }

    mpq.track(action, values);
}
```

You could add extra validation to check that dataTrack[ 1] has a length > 0 if it is possible that someone would pass "value1,,value3".

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just check to make sure they are not empty? Also you could use the ternary operator to have a default value if they are empty (i.e. action == undefined ? "Default" : datatrack[0];).

Comment: There's a more-idiomatic way to do this in Javascript. See my answer.

Comment: @Matt Ball Just saw it. I agree, your's is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 values[dataTrack[1]] = dataTrack[2];
```

with

```
if(dataTrack.length > 2){
 values[dataTrack[1]] = dataTrack[2];
}
```